# how to can add google text to speech TTS to flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hey there I'm wondering what I need to add google text to speech like what we see in the picture when click to microphone icon he speak the text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D42gH.jpg)

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251705/how-to-add-google-text-to-speech-tts-to-flutter

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll have to add the following to the dependencies (in your pubspec.yaml file):

```
flutter_tts: ^0.2.4
```

Then run from command line:

> flutter packages get

After you have done these two steps you'll have to import

```
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
```

and then instantiate inside your class:

```
FlutterTts flutterTts = 'Whatever text you what to listen to';
```

Inside the body of your scaffold you'll now have to add a RaisedButton which has an Icon as it's child and the onPressed method which contains the method to convert your text to audio.

```
Scaffold(
body: Center(
child: RaisedButton(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
child: Icon(Icons.volume_up, color: Colors.grey),
onPressed: () {
flutterTts.speak(flutterTts);
},
)
)
)
```